# How I Can Switch to other user to read file on unix

Tags: linux

Hi I want to switch to other user to read file. I don't  want to use `sudo` command for that. Can you please tell me how  i can achieve this in best way.

Comment: `su <username>` should do the trick.

Comment: *And they say Linux is complicated...* You want to switch to another user... without using `sudo`, nor `su`... which are designed for this very purpose, and more. We could certainly use more details about your **(real)** problem here...

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
su - otheruser
```

to switch to *otheruser*.  When you're done, to exit and go back to your user shell, type `logout`.

The `-` (or `-l`) option in `su` will start the shell as a new login shell with the correct environment variables set.

EDIT: another possibility is

```
runuser -u otheruser cat myfile
```

This will print onscreen *myfile* as *otheruser*. You need to be `root` to issue the `runuser`command.

Comment: Hi thanks you for  your  reply but i dont want to  do su

Comment: You could use `runuser` if you're root; please check the edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

ssh root@localhost

change username to suite your needs if root is not needed

If you indeed need root login - you may need to make following changes

- sshd_config : PermitRootLogin yes